# to subject to severe and persistent cross-examination or questioning

Tags: translation

What's the idiomatic German for *to subject to severe and persistent cross-examination or questioning*?

> jemanden massiv ins Kreuzfeuer nehmen
>
> jemanden scharf verhören

Comment: I am sorry about my question: I am not sure if that is   
 idiomatically correct

Answer (score 5):

First of all, *cross-examination* is Kreuz**verhör** in German, not Kreuz**feuer** (*cross fire*). That said, it depends on the situation: a *Verhör* is something that the police does, questioning a person who "helps them with their inquiries". A *Kreuzverhör*, on the other hand, is something that happens in court under some legal systems. If that's what you mean, I'd suggest:

> jemanden intensiv befragen; ins Kreuzverhör nehmen; einem scharfen und ausdauernden Kreuzverhör unterziehen.

Comment: Was ist ein _dauerndes_ Kreuzverhör? Wenn schon dann langandauernd, oder vielleicht ausgiebig. Und warum _severe_ = umfassend?

Comment: `andauernd` iSv "lang andauernd" meinte ich auch. Umfassend würde besser zu extensive etc. passen. Severe hat finde ich das Problem, dass es eine leicht negative Konnotation hat, die kommt zwar bei "scharf" mit, aber ich finde auch nicht zu 100%.  Alles in allem kommt der Kommentar oben weg, weil in der Tat nicht gut ist.